# Infinitely many solutions of matrix by square and determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, infinity

I have two questions (True/False and why):

1.
If:
$$Ax=b$$ has Infinitely many solutions, does necessarily $$A^2x=b$$ has Infinitely many solutions too?

2.
If det($A_{n \times n}$)=2, det($B_{n \times n}$)=-2, where $n=4$, does it mean that: $$(A+B)x=0$$ has Infinitely many solutions?

Thank you.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: Hint: for (1) note that $A^2 x = A(Ax) = Ab = b$.

Comment: What is $n$ in question 2 ?

Comment: @Gribouillis the size of the matrix, nxn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **No:** if $A = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $b = \begin{pmatrix}1\\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$, then for any scalar $\lambda$, the vector $x = \begin{pmatrix}\lambda\\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ is solution of $Ax=b$, but $A^2=0$, hence the equation $A^2 x = b$ has no solution.
2. **No**: take $$A =\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\\ 0&1&0&0\\\ 0&0&1&0 \\\ 0&0&0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
   \qquad B = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\\ 0&-2&0&0\\\ 0&0&1&0 \\\ 0&0&0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
   $$

Comment: But if a matrix is the **0** matrix doesn't that means that every solution is accepted?

Comment: If $A^2 = 0$, then $A^2 x = 0$ for all $x$. But here we have $b \not = 0$.

Comment: Oh that's right, I've practiced a lot with b=0 and totally got confused, thanks

Comment: The situation is different when $b = 0$. In this case, 1. is true.

Comment: Looking at the matrices, what made you want to contrast the the question and not solve it equationally(if you get me)?

Comment: No, I don't understand this question. If you mean why do I seek a counterexample instead of trying to prove that the result is true, the answer is that I feel immediately by experience that the results are false.

Comment: To contrast a question you need to have a hint about if it is correct or not as searching for the specific case in which the answer is wrong may consume time, so have you solved it first or went straight into contradicting and why?

Comment: For 1. I see that $b$ is in the image of $A$, so I ask if there is a way to prevent $b$ from being in the image of $A^2$. A nilpotent matrix is the most obvious way to have a small image for $A^2$. For 2. I simply know that it cannot be true because sums of matrices don't interact nicely with determinants and no miracle can happen.